# UIView with a UIWebView inside and UIActivityIndicatorView not visible over UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, storyboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIView` with a `UINavigationCorntoller` and placed a webView inside the `UIView`. Below I have a button. In the corresponding .h- and .m-file I set the up the activityIndicator which works and is visible during loading if placed below the webView. When positioning it over the webView it isn't visible. What is going wrong? What has to be changed?
[image: this works fine]

[image: The activity Indicator is positioned below the Web View to be on top]

[image: Doing this the activityIndicator is not visible during loading process]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this where your view is being set up (viewWillAppear)

```
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:<activity indicator>];
```

Or you might have to remove the activity indicator from the parent view and insert on top of web view.

Set a breakpoint and check if the indicator is really getting hidden behind the web view by analyzing all the views and their order.

```
NSArray *viewList = [self.view subviews];
```

Comment: Thank you very much - "bringSubviewToFront" solved the problem.